# Convert Key Value pair as Object for JSON response?

Tags: java, json, dictionary, object, multimap

I have the following JSON response

```
"KeyValue1": [
            {
                "test1": "1",
                "test2": "2",
            },
            {
                "test1": "3",
                "test2": "4",
            }
           ],
"KeyValue2": [
            {
                "test1": "5",
                "test2": "6",
            }
           ]
```

This is Key-value representation of a MultiMap to JSON Response, I would like to see the Key as top level variable  instead of a key-value representation.
Something like this

```
MultipleMap<Key,Value> to

Class {
String Key;
List<> Values;
}
```

For each key I might have a one or more values

Is there a easy way to do conversion for this ?

Comment: Traverse the values for each key, put them into a list, save the list together with your key. What is your problem?

Comment: You have to write custom serializer. Real code depends on what JSON library do you use because these all have different way to specify custom serializer